# React-Virtualized InfiniteLoader lags on passing props to rendered rows

Tags: react-virtualized

I just got started with react-virtualized and setup an InfiniteLoader->AutoSizer->VirtualScroller. Unfortunately, the rows that are lazily loaded aren't getting their props immediately. They render as if the props were null or undefined. If I scroll on past them and then scroll back to them, they are rendered correctly. Also, other than the initial pre-fetched rows, if I scroll slowly, all new rows render okay. If I send the scroll wheel flying, however, it will "land" on a set of "sub-rendered" rows. Given the code below, what am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { stitch } from 'keo'
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules'
import css from './component.scss'
import R from 'ramda'
import { Divider, Paper } from 'material-ui'
import { AutoSizer, InfiniteLoader, VirtualScroll } from 'react-virtualized'
import 'react-virtualized/styles.css'
import Row from 'components/Row'

let list = R.repeat({score: 100, volume: 999}, 10)

function isRowLoaded ({ index }) {
  return !!list[index]
}

function loadMoreRows ({ startIndex, stopIndex }) {
  // fake loading
  list = R.insertAll(startIndex, R.repeat({score: 100, volume: 999}, stopIndex - startIndex), list)
  return Promise.resolve()
}

const render = ({ props }) => (
    <div>
      <Paper zDepth={2}>
        <Paper zDepth={2}>
        </Paper>
        <div>
          <InfiniteLoader
            isRowLoaded={isRowLoaded}
            loadMoreRows={loadMoreRows}
            rowCount={1000}
          >
            {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
              <AutoSizer>
                {({ height, width }) => (
                  <VirtualScroll
                    ref={registerChild}
                    width={width}
                    height={height}
                    rowCount={1000}
                    rowHeight={72}
                    onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                    rowRenderer={
                      ({ index }) =>
                        <div>
                          <Row {...list[index]} />
                          <Divider />
                        </div>
                    }
                  />
                )}
              </AutoSizer>
            )}
          </InfiniteLoader>
        </div>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  )

export const View = CSSModules(stitch({ render }), css)
```

Comment: I believe the problem has to deal with the way you're updating the `list` array. I'm not very familiar with `stitch` but I believe your `render` function isn't being re-called when you push new items onto `list`.

Comment: The code you've shared for `isRowLoaded`, `loadMoreRows`, and `rowRenderer` should work just fine.

Comment: @brianvaughn Thanks. I'll give it a try with traditional classes and see if that changes things. After that, I'll take a look at how I'm updating the list.

Comment: @brianvaughn It turned out that it was an enhancement to my shouldComponentUpdate for Row that was causing the issue. All working now. Thanks for your help.